# Get values from webpage (Dynamic)

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, parsing

How can I get value's from a webpage like this: http://www.soccerstand.com/h2h/soccer/1505918

I can't read the source of it, because it's loaded dynamically?

Comment: I take it you want to scrape the live score data? You could pay for it rather than steal it. http://www.enetpulse.com/products/xml-feed/live-score

Comment: It's for personal use, I don't like the overview of the site, so I make a piece of code that will parse it to jtabel for myself. I don't steal it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, content is generated dynamically.
You can use their script from http://js.enetscores.com/, or try to trace with browser and get real links like this one

http://www.soccerstand.com/snippet/h2h_against?theme=default&eventFK=1505918&type=results&limit=10&sort=date_desc&no_header=1&_=1383140625983

Comment: Where did you get that url from?

Comment: If you are using chrome - Ctrl+Alt+J then in Network. If you are using IE  - F12 , then in Network